# Polyline arcs above surface in cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

Cesium polylines follow the curvature of the earth, between two points, by default.  How do I make arcs, which go above the ground, like in this example?

http://armsglobe.chromeexperiments.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example using an interpolation algorithm on Entity positions to compute the smooth arcs.  Try [loading this in Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/index.html#c=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).

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');

var numberOfArcs = 50;
var startLon = -74;
var startLat = 39;

viewer.clock.clockRange = Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP;

var startTime = viewer.clock.startTime;
var midTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(startTime, 43200, new Cesium.JulianDate());
var stopTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(startTime, 86400, new Cesium.JulianDate());

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfArcs; ++i) {
    var color = Cesium.Color.fromRandom({
        alpha : 1.0
    });
    var stopLon = Cesium.Math.nextRandomNumber() * 358 - 179;
    var stopLat = Cesium.Math.nextRandomNumber() * 178 - 89;

    // Create a straight-line path.
    var property = new Cesium.SampledPositionProperty();
    var startPosition = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(startLon, startLat, 0);
    property.addSample(startTime, startPosition);
    var stopPosition = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(stopLon, stopLat, 0);
    property.addSample(stopTime, stopPosition);

    // Find the midpoint of the straight path, and raise its altitude.
    var midPoint = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(property.getValue(midTime));
    midPoint.height = Cesium.Math.nextRandomNumber() * 500000 + 2500000;
    var midPosition = viewer.scene.globe.ellipsoid.cartographicToCartesian(
        midPoint, new Cesium.Cartesian3());

    // Redo the path to be the new arc.
    property = new Cesium.SampledPositionProperty();
    property.addSample(startTime, startPosition);
    property.addSample(midTime, midPosition);
    property.addSample(stopTime, stopPosition);

    // Create an Entity to show the arc.
    var arcEntity = viewer.entities.add({
        position : property,
        // The point is optional, I just wanted to see it.
        point : {
            pixelSize : 8,
            color : Cesium.Color.TRANSPARENT,
            outlineColor : color,
            outlineWidth : 3
        },
        // This path shows the arc as a polyline.
        path : {
            resolution : 1200,
            material : new Cesium.PolylineGlowMaterialProperty({
                glowPower : 0.16,
                color : color
            }),
            width : 10,
            leadTime: 1e10,
            trailTime: 1e10
        }
    });

    // This is where it becomes a smooth path.
    arcEntity.position.setInterpolationOptions({
        interpolationDegree : 5,
        interpolationAlgorithm : Cesium.LagrangePolynomialApproximation
    });
}
```

Comment: I think the glowMaterial has rendering artifacts, when the arc's plane is positioned perpendicular to the screen, in other words, when the front of the arc covers up the back of the arc.

Comment: This is an awesome example, and thanks for sharing. I am wondering though, if there is a time-agnostic way to do this? I am trying to apply an arc to a collection of polylines I'm keeping track of, and time has never been important (they don't represent routes or trajectories). The SampledPositionProperty that makes it all tick really wants those ReferenceFrames though. Any ideas on how to implement this without bringing time into the mix?

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle Thanks!  I added a new answer here to address your question:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/42348428/836708

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar implementation here, but it was difficult to find:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/vr_ZH1yRNoQ